# Need to get a specific class exists in HTML body

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to check if **class = "special-price"** exists in below code. 
 Here is html code :

```
<div class="product-shop">
 <div class="f-fix">
    <h2 class="product-name newname"> <a href="#" title=""> Xiaomi Mi Band 2 Strap (Black with White Border) </a></h2>
    <!--product price-->
    <div class="text-center ">
        <div class="price-box">
            <p class="old-price"> <span class="price-label">Regular Price:</span > 
              <span class = "price" id = "old-price-8846" > ৳200 </span>
            </p > 
            <p class = "special-price" > 
             <span class = "price-label"> Special Price </span> 
             <span class="price" itemprop="price" content="149" id="product-price-8846"> ৳149 </span>
          </p>
      </div> 
  </div > 
</div>
```

I am using Scrapy with python. After checking if the class found I need to collect text of **class="price"**.

Comment: What have you tried already? What errors/output did you get?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like:

```
if response.css('.special-price'):
    price = response.css('.price::text').get()  # or do whatever you need
```

or for short:

```
price = response.css('.special-price .price::text').get()
```

it will give you None in case there is no element with `special-price` class.

Comment: I tried with this and it works. As a newbie I am  struggling with store this data on a variable and print the output. Here is my Code:  "def parse(self, response):
        self.log('I just visited: ' + response.url)
        target_div = response.css('div.product-shop>div.f-fix>div.text-center')
        for item in target_div:
            if item.response.css('.special-price'):
                 price = response.css('.price::text').get()
                 return price
            else:
                price = response.css('.regular-price .price::text').get()
                return price"